# I have 2 divs in one component, in first div i have navigation ul list and second div is for content

Tags: jquery, html, angular, angular8

> Now i want to show the data in second div by click the corresponding nav link , Means when i click on random link then its show random input tag in content div

```
<div id="wrapper" class="active" class="container">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper-1" >
    <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar"> 
      <li ><a class="leftbar-header"  href="#" (click)="panelExpanded=!panelExpanded" >Tag Data</a>
        <ul class="sub-element" > 
          <li  class="element"><a  href="#" *ngIf="panelExpanded">Random</a></li>
          <li class="element"><a href="#" *ngIf="panelExpanded">Ramp</a> </li>
          <li class="element"><a href="#" *ngIf="panelExpanded">Sign</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li ><a class="leftbar-header"  href="#" (click)="panelExpanded2=!panelExpanded2" >Gauges Data</a>
        <ul class="sub-element" > 
          <li (click)="test()"  class="element"><a  href="#"*ngIf="panelExpanded2">Random</a></li>
          <li  class="element"><a href="#"*ngIf="panelExpanded2" >Ramp</a></li>
          <li  class="element"><a href="#"*ngIf="panelExpanded2">Sign</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content" >


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gl4gha?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

.html

```
<li  class="element">
    <a  href="#" *ngIf="panelExpanded" (click)="content = 'Random'">Random</a>
</li>

<div class="content">
    <p (click)="getContent(content)"> {{content}} </p>
</div>
```

.ts

```
  content = '';

  getContent(content){
    alert(content)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks For help, but if i had render any element like div or canvas onclick() in the content then what should i do.

Comment: Check the modified answer/demo